# Speaker recognition open source C++

Tags: open-source, c++, voice-recognition

Can anyone help me to find a simple open source speaker recognition project on C++?

Maybe made with SAPI (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125077(v=vs.85).aspx) or something else.

I need to authenticate users.